# Unresolved reference in kotlin for object that exist in resource

Tags: kotlin

I've a object in android studio kotlin app\src\main\res\TestData.kt but app compilation fails with error Unresolved reference. How do I refer to this object from activity?

compilation error unresoved reference

[This part of the code throws "Unresolved reference"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf33B.png)

Comment: you should post the code of class/object that you are trying to access, and how you are accessing it

Comment: Kotlin code files need to be in `main/kotlin` or `main/java`, not in `main/res`.